# I have a phone that is completely locked and usb debugging is off. How can i make the phone usable again?

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms

this phone is a lg stlyo 2 model : LGL82VL

The phone was pattern locked, and a gmail was set up. The phone was factory data reset. yet its asking for the gmail and password to finish the process. I do not have the gmail. Usb debugging is off. If i attempt to use adb is just replies with error: device '(null)' not found

How can i erase the phones rom and write a new one to make this phone usable again?

And I have already tried most if not all of the tricks on youtube of tricking the phone to let me into google and copy and paste a new gmail. That did not work. Also i cannot use the keys to bring me into any other menu to get into the file system.

At this point I would be completely okay with erasing the phones rom entirely and starting from scratch. I just need to know if its do-able and how to do it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have twrp? If it does perhaps there is another way around that helps to reset forgotten pattern lock / security PIN / password from your Android device without having to lose your precious data. 
 folder, thus resetting Android’s security.
Ketan from XDA Developers forum has developed an intelligent hack file, that needs to be flashed on your Android device through custom recovery and bingoo!! your phone’s security code / pattern lock and password will be removed. This hack basically instructs your phone to remove the files which tell android that the phone is locked to show the lock ui. If the device is protected with a pin or password it will skip it. If it's protected with pattern then it will not skip it but don't worry you can input any pattern to unlock it. Downloads: http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=2245081&d=1378720290 I hope it helps if it doesn't tell me there's another way to do it!!